# What is the difference between om2m & onem2m

Tags: iot, onem2m

OK I got "the purpose and goal of oneM2M is to develop technical specifications which address the need for a common M2M Service Layer that can be readily embedded within various hardware and software, and relied upon to connect the myriad of devices in the field with M2M application servers worldwide." for oneM2M.

And om2m is "The OM2M project, initiated by LAAS-CNRS, is an open source implementation of the ETSI M2M standard. It provides a horizontal M2M service platform for developing services independently of the underlying network, with the aim to facilitate the deployment of vertical applications and heterogeneous devices."

my questions: 1) Is om2m (open source project) based on oneM2M standard ? 2) Is there any project developing/ed based on oneM2M standard ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OM2M is based on ETSI standard (European Telecommunications Standards Institute) for M2M now called smartM2M. But ETSI is one the founder of OneM2M initiative. So you will find a lot of ideas and principle of smartM2M inside OneM2M.
We estimate at LAAS-CNRS that the overlap is around 70 to 80%. So OM2M is not far away from OneM2M standard. The first official version of OneM2M standard will be publisher in january 2015.
We will do a first demonstration of OM2M with OneM2M partial implementation in december 2014 with other partners at the launch event of OneM2M.

Thierry Monteil
co-founder of OM2M
LAAS-CNRS

Comment: Thank you, I also talked with Mahdi, he also gave some informations. Thank You both.

Comment: hi, I am also starting to do a project about developing M2M Applications based on ETSI standard. I also use OM2M as horizontal service platform. Right now I am looking for some documentation about the General concept for OM2M fit to OneM2M ETSI standard. Could you recommend me some documentations about this? Thank you so much

Comment: @Sonn have you developed the application based on onem2m?

Comment: @VarshneyP. yes I had last year a small project to build an application based on oneM2M standard